# Trouble adding to an array inside a loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops

I'm making a thing to help me keep track of my players for d&d and i hit a roadblock. relevant piece of code:

```ruby
playercount = nil
playername = nil

playernamegroup = Array.new
playeracgroup = Array.new
playermaxhpgroup = Array.new
playercurrenthpgroup = Array.new


def party(n)
  return if n == 0
  party(n-1)

  player = {}
  puts "-What's player #{n}'s name?"
  playername = gets.chomp 
  playernamegroup <<  playername    
  puts "-What's their AC?"
  playerac = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "-Got it. What's their max HP?"
  playermaxhp = gets.chomp.to_i
  $players[n] = player
  puts "-Okay."
end
```

there's a loop further down that runs the party block the number of times given, here:

```ruby
loop do
  puts "-How many players today?"  
  playercount = gets.chomp.to_i
    if 0 >= playercount
      puts "-You can't have no players in a party. That's not D&D, that's you having no friends."
      redo
   elsif 8 < playercount
     puts "-Hey now, that's a huge party. I can only handle eight players at once."
     redo
    elsif 8 >= playercount
      break     
   else 
     puts "-A number between 1 and 8, please."
     redo
   end
end

$players = [] 

party(playercount)
```

when i run it i get:
Error: undefined method `playernamegroup' for main:Object

i've tried shuffling things around and still get the same error, and i've looked through other asks and haven't figured it out. help?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Add player stats to arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the arrays inside your function

```
def party(n)
  playernamegroup = Array.new
  playeracgroup = Array.new
  playermaxhpgroup = Array.new
  playercurrenthpgroup = Array.new

  return if n == 0
  party(n-1)

  player = {}
  puts "-What's player #{n}'s name?"
  playername = gets.chomp 
  playernamegroup <<  playername    
  puts "-What's their AC?"
  playerac = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "-Got it. What's their max HP?"
  playermaxhp = gets.chomp.to_i
  $players[n] = player
  puts "-Okay."
end
```